# Magento website user account pages unavailable. How to find what is the problem?

Tags: magento-1.9, debugging

In our newly created website account pages such as "my account", "my wishlist", "my cart" etc have all become unavailable, when requested browser loads for awhile and then returns "connection has timed out" page. I have debugging mode turned on and error logs turned on however there is nothing there that could tell me where to start fixing this problem. Has anyone had a similar problem? Can anyone advise what to do in this particular situation. I tried million things already to no success. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out what the issue was. It was because of my HTTPS settings in magento System->Configuration->Web. while testing I have enabled HTTPS and forgot about it. Of course because certificate was not installed or configured on the server that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error "connection has timed out" seems you are using some redirect code in somewhere. Well for debug you could see below things

1. For **my account** find "customer_account_index" in theme layout files.
2. For **my wishlist** find "wishlist_index_index" in theme layout files.
3. For **my cart** find "checkout_cart_index" in theme layout files.

   It will show you all templates & block files using that page & then find out the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes I was thinking the same, some redirect code has been automatically generated somewhere. I have removed the .html extension from my URL recently by going to System -> Config -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations and removing .html, but later changed it back.

Comment: Also I had added a redirect line in Magento's .htacess file for one link to redirect to external blog, but have removed that also to no success.

Comment: No, redirect code would be in some phtml or script files. Just check if any third party extension you are using in your website related with these pages & try to disable & check.

Comment: I use two extensions: stripe and ASchroder_SMTPPro. When installing the second one my site became unavailable, I had to turn off compilation then uninstall the product and install it again. Anyway I disabled the two extensions now but it did not change anything...

Comment: There are few more things you could check

1. If any local module overrides the Customer module files.
2. There is configuration setting as "Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in" that is used in file /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php check that file.
3. clear cache & try in private window.

No more solutions are possible. :(